# How do I stop the constant requests for a password?

Tags: password, lock-screen

I am 70 years old and losing my memory. The only other person here is my wife, who I trust with **everything**.

I have Ubuntu set to automatically log me in when I boot the system. I need to stop the constant password requests when I walk away from the computer for a while.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but just an idea. You could set a password where you just drag your finger over the top row of keys or something similar. I do the same on mine because I got tired of tipping in my complicated root password.

Answer (score 55):

There is an *easily changed* setting to prevent these requests for your password whenever you need to walk away from your computer for a while.

First follow this path:

```
Dash --> System Settings --> Personal --> Brightness & Lock
```

Then take the following two steps:

1. Set the 'Lock' setting to 'Off'
2. *Uncheck* the setting 'Require my Password when waking from suspend'

I have tested this successfully with both Trusty Tahr 14.04 LTS *and* Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS. Below is a screenshot from  Xenial Xerus to illustrate the technique:

[image]

Obviously this shows the setting *activated*, you need to *remove* the tick (the check in the check box) by clicking on it.

**Note:** Keep in mind that this disables a *security feature* of Ubuntu, possibly not relevant in *your* case but relevant to many other Ubuntu users. This feature is designed to protect your computer from unauthorized use by others while you are away from your computer for a period of time...

Comment: No problem, and a big 'Welcome' to Ubuntu :). I hope you enjoy both Ubuntu itself and the community that supports it...

Comment: And if this answer has solved your problem on AskUbuntu you can 'Accept' the answer by clicking the greyed out 'Tick' near my answer. This neatly wraps up the whole question and answer and shows the community what worked best for you...

Comment: What 'Tick', please?

Comment: @TomD [it should look like this](https://0ws.pw/safs.png), hit the tick below and [it'll become green like this](https://0ws.pw/28xh.png).

Comment: @TomD welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might want to check this link to understand how "accepting an answer" works: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @TomD What people in some countries call a "tick mark" people in other countries call a "check mark", and it looks like ✓. It's roughly to the left of "Set the 'Lock' setting to 'Off'" in the answer.

Comment: +1, nice answer. I really always thought that "Brightness & Lock"  is at least weird, now I know it's pretty undiscoverable...  next will be "Keyboard & Network" ;-)