# Enable password on lock screen

Tags: 16.04, password, lock-screen

I have a problem with restoring the password request on the lock screen. During the installation of Ubuntu I specified the auto-login option, but now I want to re-enable the password protection. Possible changes in the system settings don't help.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Spme insight here perhaps: http://askubuntu.com/a/768662/57576 . Of course you will do the revese suggested in that post :)

Comment: ...and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: And here: http://askubuntu.com/q/316084/57576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop the constant requests for a password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/768656/how-do-i-stop-the-constant-requests-for-a-password)

Comment: proposed solutions doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying a lot of different options and, finally, what works for me, is installation of xscreensaver

`sudo apt install xscreensaver`

I added a shortcut `Shift+Super+L` to a command:

`xscreensaver-command -lock`

and now it locks my PC and unlock can be possible only if I enter the password

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Settings >> User Accounts` and switch the `Automatic Login` to `OFF`.

Now set your preferences in the following sections:

`System Settings >> Brightness & Lock`

`System Settings >> Security & Privacy >> Security`

---

If not already existing, set a user-password, replace 'your-user-name' with your real user-name:

```
sudo passwd your-user-name
```

---

Open the following file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Remove or comment out (#) the line: `autologin-user`

Save and Exit

---

Reinstall gnome-screensaver, update and reboot your system:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-screensaver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I did, restart my PC and it shows the password entry field, but I was not able to enter there anything. Once I click on keyboard it immediately log me in. Possibly more details may be helpfull

Comment: At the startup the system asks my for a "default keyring password", maybe this is an issue?

Comment: You have no password for your user account: see above in the answer how to set a password for a user...

Comment: I did like Neni said, but no changes. Still not asking me for a passoword. Any other ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer, give it another try. I can't simulate your problem on my Laptop, so let's try step by step...

Comment: I tried with lightdm.conf and reinstalation of screensaver - no result. Still after the reboot it is enough to click enter to login and `super+L` just show a black screen with no password protection

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED problem with restoring the password request on the lock screen:

1. Log into the main admin account.
2. Create a temporary administrator account.
3. Log in to the temp admin account.
4. Change password and lock setting for the main admin account.
5. Log out and confirm the main admin account lock setting are functioning correctly.
6. Clean up temp account as desired.
7. Done!